# How to return a value from OnGet or OnPost method to in ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I've a c# class like below sample code

```
public IActionResult OnPostTranJarray(int transaction_number, string cardholder)
    {
    
    dynamic Trans = GetTransactions(transaction_number,cardholder);
    
    return Trans;
   }
```

OR

```
public JArray Transactions { get; set; }
public void OnGet(int transaction_number)
{
  Transactions =  GetTransactions(transaction_number);   
}
```

just wanted to Make a post call inside the IndexModel Class. I've use these below code in jquery

```
 $.post("https://localhost:7197/Transactions?handler=TranJarray?transaction_number="+transactionNumb+"&cardholder="+cardHolderName, response => { 
      alert("response",response);
    });

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://localhost:7197/Transactions?handler=TranJarray?transaction_number="+transactionNumb+"&cardholder="+cardHolderName,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",    
async: true,
cache: false,
success: function (data)
{  
    alert("success");
    fnLoadTbl();
  
}
});
```

But it's not hitting to the method.. but if i make ajax GET Request to OnGet method it's hitting but not returning any value. so let me know if you have any idea. Thanks..

Comment: Add `return Json(Transactions)` to the `onGet` and change the function type to an `ActionResult`

Comment: but it's jarray

Comment: What does it change that it is a JArray? What is the output you get, when you return it as @JamesS proposed?

Comment: if i did like   "return Json(Transactions)"     I'm getting    "The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context" error

Comment: @VasanthR Is this in a `Controller`? If so you need to inherit from the `Controller` class

Comment: It's not controller just a class inherited page model

Comment: In Razor Page, you need use `return new JsonResult(Transactions)`. But you said it not working in your side, what do you mean not working? The data cannot display? What's the version of asp.net core? If the version is beyond asp.net core 3.0, pls rememeber to add newtonsoft support(`AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson()`), otherwise you will receive empty Jarray.

Answer (score 2):

In order to return JSON from your `OnGet` method, change the return type from `void` to `IActionResult` and return a `JsonResult`, e.g.:

```
public JArray Transactions { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnGet(int transaction_number)
{
  Transactions =  GetTransactions(transaction_number);   
  return new JsonResult(Transactions);
}
```

Comment: in my case this one not working

Comment: In which way does it not work? Do you get an error or is the returned JSON not correct?

Comment: Hi Markus I've updated the question i think we've to make post call and onpost method to return value.. but my post call is not hitting to onpost method

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution by doing these

1. We've to create a model class like this

   ```
   public class PersonModel
    {  [BindProperty]
        public int TransactionNumber { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string FormName { get; set; }
    }
   ```

2.Created a onpost method

```
 public void  OnPostSubmit(PersonModel person)
    {        
        this.trnTable =   GetTransactions(person.TransactionNumber,
        person.FormName);       
       
    }
```

3.In frontend we should have  and a  type="submit" button inside it

```
 <form id="statementId" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <dl  class=" col-2 dl-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group" style="max-width: 200px;">
                 <label>Form</label>
                <input id="form" name="FormName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Form">
                 <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
            </div>
        </dl>
    
        <dl class=" col-2 dl-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group" style="max-width: 200px;">
                            <label>Transaction Number</label>
                             <input type="text" name="TransactionNumber" placeholder="Type" class="form-control" >
                              <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
        </div>
        </dl>
     </div>
            <input style="max-width: 100px;max-height: 40px;margin-left: 10px;"  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" asp-page-handler="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then it's perfectly working.. but thanks for those who tried to answer it